# One of three forms on my page will not calculate

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.aquaticsystems.com/chemapp2.html

The CSS and JS are in the page, not linked because I didn't want the background from the site. In any case, it was and is working for the first two forms but when I added the 3rd one, which was just copy/paste and change the names and 1 number, the third one doesn't calculate and seems to be looking for something from the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Herbicide Calculators</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.title {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;color: #15649D;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;}
.txt {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #333;}
.txt2 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;color: #15649D;}
.table {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #333;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-top-style: none;border-right-style: none;border-bottom-style: none;border-left-style: none;}
.calculator {float: left;width: 280px;padding: 3px;border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;color: #000;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;margin-left: 3px;border: thin solid #333;}
.calculator .form-row {overflow: auto;padding: 2px 2px;border: thin solid #333;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;}
.calculator .form-row LABEL {float: left;width: 130px;line-height: 2em;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.calculator .form-row INPUT {float: right;width: 130px;}
.calculator .form-row.last-row {background-color: #9FECF2;}
.calculator .form-row.last-rowb {background-color: #A7D2F3;color: #333;}
.calculator .form-row-buttons {text-align: center;margin-top: 5px;}
.calculator SMALL {line-height: 0.7em;font-size: 10px;}
.calculator DD {font-size: 11px;font-style: italic;margin-bottom: 0;}
.calculator DT {font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#a_qty_calculator').submit(function() {a_qty_calc(); return false;});
  $('#b_qty_calculator').submit(function() {b_qty_calc(); return false;});
    $('#c_qty_calculator').submit(function() {c_qty_calc(); return false;});
});
  function a_qty_calc() {
  var pr = parseFloat($('#pr').val());
  var sw = parseFloat($('#sw').val());
  var ad = parseFloat($('#ad').val());
  var dc = parseFloat($('#dc').val());
  var pg = parseFloat($('#pg').val());

  var ta = Math.round((pr * sw) / 43560 * 10) / 10;
  var taf = Math.round(ad * ta * 10) / 10;
  var ga = Math.round((taf * dc * 2.72) / pg * 10) / 10;
  var oa = Math.round(ga * 128 * 10) / 10;
  var gab = Math.round(ga / 1000 * 100) / 100;
  var oab = Math.round(gab * 128 * 100) / 100;
  $('#ta').val(ta);
  $('#taf').val(taf);
  $('#ga').val(ga);
  $('#oa').val(oa);
  $('#gab').val(gab);
  $('#oab').val(oab);
}

function b_qty_calc() {
  var wad = parseFloat($('#wad').val());
  var wdc = parseFloat($('#wdc').val());
  var wpg = parseFloat($('#wpg').val());
  var wta = parseFloat($('#wta').val());

  var wtaf = Math.round(wad * wta * 10) / 10;
  var wga = Math.round((wtaf * wdc * 2.72) / wpg * 10) / 10;
  var woa = Math.round(wga * 128 * 10) / 10;
  var wgab = Math.round(wga / 1000 * 100) / 100;
  var woab = Math.round(wgab * 128 * 100) / 100;
  $('#wtaf').val(wtaf);
  $('#wga').val(wga); 
  $('#woa').val(woa);  
  $('#wgab').val(wgab); 
  $('#woab').val(woab);  
}

  function c_qty_calc() {
  var ppr = parseFloat($('#ppr').val());
  var psw = parseFloat($('#psw').val());
  var pad = parseFloat($('#pad').val());
  var pdc = parseFloat($('#pdc').val());
  var ppg = parseFloat($('#ppg').val());

  var pta = Math.round((ppr * psw) / 43560 * 10) / 10;
  var ptaf = Math.round(pad * pta * 10) / 10;
  var pga = Math.round((ptaf * pdc * 2.72) / pg * 10) / 10;
  var poa = Math.round(pga * 16 * 10) / 10;
  var pgab = Math.round(pga / 1000 * 100) / 100;
  var poab = Math.round(pgab * 16 * 100) / 100;
  $('#pta').val(pta);
  $('#ptaf').val(ptaf);
  $('#pga').val(pga);
  $('#poa').val(poa);
  $('#pgab').val(pgab);
  $('#poab').val(poab);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="508" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td width="60%">
<form action="" class="calculator" id="a_qty_calculator" method="post">
<span class="title">ASI Perimeter Treatment: Liquid</span>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="pr">Perimeter</label>
    <input id="pr" name="pr" type="text"/>
  </div>
    <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="sw">Swath Width</label>
    <input id="sw" name="sw" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="ad">Average Depth</label>
    <input id="ad" name="ad" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="dc">Desired Concentration</label>
    <input id="dc" name="dc" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="pg">Lbs of AI/Gallon</label>
    <input id="pg" name="pg" type="text"/>
  </div>
    <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="ta">Treatment Acres</label>
    <input id="ta" name="ta" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="taf">Treatment Area Acre Ft</label>
    <input id="taf" name="taf" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="ga">Gallons to Apply PPM</label>
    <input id="ga" name="ga" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="oa">Ounces to Apply PPM</label>
    <input id="oa" name="oa" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-rowb">
    <label for="gab">Gallons to Apply PPB</label>
    <input id="gab" name="gab" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-rowb">
    <label for="oab">Ounces to Apply PPB</label>
    <input id="oab" name="oab" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row-buttons">
     <input type='submit' id='submit' value="Calculate" />
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </div>
</form></td>
    <td width="40%" rowspan="3"><table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="table">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="2" class="txt2">Pounds of Active Ingredient per <br />
          Gallon or Pounds of Product</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="98">2, 4-D Amine </td>
        <td width="55"> 3.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Aquathol K</td>
        <td>3.0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Captain</td>
        <td>0.91 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Clipper</td>
        <td>0.51</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CuSO4</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cutrine Plus</td>
        <td>0.91</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Diquat</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fluridone AS</td>
        <td> 4.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Habitat </td>
        <td>2.0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hydrothol 191</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Komeen</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Navigate</td>
        <td>0.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Solar Genesis</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form action="" class="calculator" id="b_qty_calculator" method="post">
      <span class="title">ASI Whole Lake Treatment: Liquid</span>
      <div class="form-row optional">
        <label for="wta">Treatment Acres</label>
        <input id="wta" name="wta" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional">
        <label for="wad">Average Depth</label>
        <input id="wad" name="wad" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional">
        <label for="wdc">Desired Concentration</label>
        <input id="wdc" name="wdc" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional">
        <label for="wpg">Lbs of AI/Gallon</label>
        <input id="wpg" name="wpg" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional last-row">
        <label for="wtaf">Treatment Area Acre Ft</label>
        <input id="wtaf" name="wtaf" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional last-row">
        <label for="wga">Gallons to Apply PPM</label>
        <input id="wga" name="wga" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional last-row">
        <label for="woa">Ounces to Apply PPM</label>
        <input id="woa" name="woa" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional last-rowb">
        <label for="wgab">Gallons to Apply PPB</label>
        <input id="wgab" name="wgab" type="text"/>
        </div>
      <div class="form-row optional last-rowb">
        <label for="woab">Ounces to Apply PPB</label>
        <input id="woab" name="woab" type="text"/>
        </div>
  <div class="form-row-buttons">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
    </form></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><form action="" class="calculator" id="c_qty_calculator" method="post">
<span class="title">ASI Perimeter Treatment: Liquid</span>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="ppr">Perimeter</label>
    <input id="ppr" name="ppr" type="text"/>
  </div>
    <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="psw">Swath Width</label>
    <input id="psw" name="psw" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="pad">Average Depth</label>
    <input id="pad" name="pad" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="pdc">Desired Concentration</label>
    <input id="pdc" name="pdc" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional">
    <label for="ppg">Lbs of AI/Gallon</label>
    <input id="ppg" name="ppg" type="text"/>
  </div>
    <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="pta">Treatment Acres</label>
    <input id="pta" name="pta" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="ptaf">Treatment Area Acre Ft</label>
    <input id="ptaf" name="ptaf" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="pga">Gallons to Apply PPM</label>
    <input id="pga" name="pga" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-row">
    <label for="poa">Ounces to Apply PPM</label>
    <input id="poa" name="poa" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-rowb">
    <label for="pgab">Gallons to Apply PPB</label>
    <input id="pgab" name="pgab" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row optional last-rowb">
    <label for="poab">Ounces to Apply PPB</label>
    <input id="poab" name="poab" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row-buttons">
     <input type='submit' id='submit' value="Calculate" />
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </div>
</form></td></tr>
</table>
<p class="txt">&copy;2012 Aquatic Systems, Inc. All rights reserved</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this

```
var pga = Math.round((ptaf * pdc * 2.72) / pg * 10) / 10;
```

line `pg` must be `ppg`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I redid is 3 times and missed that one every time.

Comment: Perhaps this is a sign that that wall of code needs refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how to use a Herbicide Calculater, and I've got no data to test it with it's pretty hard to figure out what's wrong with your code, but one thing that I do see, is that you've copy-pasted the 3rd form a little too well. The submit button has the same id='submit' as the form before.

And on line 78, you use a variable called 'pg' which hasn't been initialized - I think you meant to use the 'ppg' variable.

A lesson to learn from this, is to name your variables properly, that'll save you for a lot of time when debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pga = Math.round((ptaf * pdc * 2.72) / ppg * 10) / 10;
```